# Vertical sizing in WPF trouble

Tags: wpf, xaml, wpftoolkit

I'm having trouble vertically sizing the CheckListBox control from https://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/. I'm a week-old newbie in WPF, so this is probably a general issue with (vertical) sizing.

Given my grid, I want the first 5 rows to size whatever size, they need to be, and in my viewport, I want the CheckListBox control in row 6 to simply fill the remaining space vertically.

My problem is, that when I fill the CheckListBox with a lot of elements, the control just expands / overflows the viewport. What I want it to do, is to assume the height of the remaining space vertically, which will make it display an inner scrollbar.

```xml
<Grid Grid.Column="0">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Label Grid.Row="0">Some title</Label>
    <RadioButton Grid.Row="1" GroupName="NameSortRadioButtonGroup">Firstname Lastname</RadioButton>
    <RadioButton Grid.Row="2" GroupName="NameSortRadioButtonGroup">Lastname, Firstname</RadioButton>
    <TextBox Grid.Row="3" Margin="0,5" />
    <Label Grid.Row="4" Content="{Binding ElementName=MyCheckListBox, Path=SelectedItems.Count}" />
    <xctk:CheckListBox
        Grid.Row="5"
        Name="MyCheckListBox"
        VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
        VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch"
        Height="Auto"
        />
</Grid>
```

I have left out some parent elements to simplify. The Grid is in a grid, that's in a canvas, that's in a grid, and this outer grid is direct child of the Window element.

I have tried wrapping the CheckListBox control in a StackPanel with Height="Auto" (to eliminate the possibility of a bug in the CheckListBox) and also here to set the height of the CheckListBox using

> Height="{Binding ElementName=CheckListBoxStackPanelWrapper, Path=ActualHeight}"

I also initially tried to do the whole thing with first a StackPanel and later a DockPanel instead of the Grid control.

In all cases, the CheckListBox just flows out of the window/viewport. If I give it an explicit height, it behaves correctly, but I obviously want my window to be resizable.

What shall I do?

Comment: is this `Grid` directly in your `Window` or it's part of some other control?

Comment: There is more stuff - it's in a grid that's in a grid that's in a canvas. The size of this canvas is the "content area" and is effectively what I'm referring to as the viewport.

Comment: `Canvas` is the problem. From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.canvas.aspx): _Child elements of a Canvas are always given the full size that they desire_. So your `Grid` will be given as much space as it requires

Comment: My good man, you are right! Thanks. Sad thing is, the canvas was only there because I was messing around to learn controls.

I have put the canvas-part in the question, so you can "answer" it officially, and I can mark your answer as the answer, and you get the points :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To sum up comments because your outer control is a `Canvas` which does not restrict its child elements From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.canvas.aspx):

> Child elements of a Canvas are always given the full size that they desire

which means that `Grid` will be given as much space as it require. One solution is to remove the `Canvas` part or restrict the size size of `Grid` or expanding row

Comment: Thanks. I removed the outer canvas, cut down on the nesting in general, and now the grid is restricting flow correctly.